# Stopping SKAction.applyForce

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

I have a ball that bouncing around the screen, the ball starts to bounce when the function touchesEnded is called:

```
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches{

        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        let ballposition = CGVector.init(dx: location.x, dy: location.y - circle.position.y)

        circle.run(SKAction.applyForce(ballposition, duration: 0.3), withKey: "move")


    }}
```

However, I have collision detection so when the ball hits a node called `bottom` I get notified

```
    if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "Bottom" && contact.bodyB.node?.name == "circle" {
            circle.removeAction(forKey: "move")
            print("Hit")

        }
    }
```

ball is named circle in the code

I want the action `SKAction.applyForce` to stop when the collision happens
I get the word "Hit" which means the detection works fine but 
circle.removeAction(forKey: "move")
does not work, idk why.

I tried `circle.removeAllActions()` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SKAction.applyForce` method only applies a force to a physics body. Removing the key will stop applying force, but wont remove current effects. To stop the body, you could change body's velocity vector:

```
 circle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector.zero
```

Comment: So that is the idea behind it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this circle is the same object as the one you are adding your action?
Try to `circle.paused = true`

Comment: yes the circle is the same object as the one I am adding to my action